# How to return a response via php

Tags: php, api

I'm writing a php api with methods wired together by php routing, such that

```
dev.myphp.com/user/login?email=sdfsdf@fdfd.com&password=d514
```

will return a json/xml response.

However, I do not know how to return this response, even if I use json_encode or xml_encode to conver the data string.

Do I just need to uniquely echo the JSON string out?

Comment: yeah, you need echo the result

Comment: 1 advice from what I see at your url..
NEVER send password as GET param!!! 
Other way you can just echo json encoded string, but must be very careful not to echo anything else perhaps with exit after the echo, otherwise your json will be not valid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to take data using POST method not GET , untill unless you don't find it less useful in caompare to POSt.

use simply

```
<?Php
--- php code 

return json_encode($resultdata);

?>
```

it would be enough.

Comment: thanks, either way, I can return a json_encode() inside a <?Php right? that means that return will refer to the <?php ?> function? or would it refer to the file index.php?

Comment: <?php here $resultdata array of data values ,   return json_encode($resultdata) ; have to be used in function where all logic of your code is going to be performed and no redirection is needed after that, as you have to retrieve that response on same url.

Comment: so in the case that i defined routing for that function, it would just be  <?php login()/*Equivalent of redirect*/; function login(){ echo json_encode($someData)} ?>, and this response will appear from  dev.myphp.com/user/login?email=sdfsdf@fdfd.com&password=d514 ?